# How to parse XML and serialize it again in a custom way which shows empty elements as expanded tags?

Tags: javascript, parsing, serialization, xml-parsing, xml-serialization

I have the following which can be dynamic

```
const data = '<users>
 <user>
  <firstname>test</firstname>
  <lastname />
  <age />
 </user>
</users>'
```

I want to find every instance where its closed with a  `/>` and expand e.g `<age />` becomes `<age></age>`

obviously I can do this with named tags e.g

`data = data.replaceAll("age />", "age></age>")`

but how do I do this globally for tags which I dont know the name?

Comment: Consider not using string replace to edit xml?

Comment: You can use regex for this of course, but are you sure your tags will never have attributes, making this task harder?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? `<age />` and `<age></age>` mean exactly the same thing in XML. (Not in HTML, but in XML.)

Comment: @Kaddath - **If** the elements you want to target will never have attributes, this is feasible with a single regex (I think). But in the general case, a single JavaScript regex handling the `y` element in the following reliably and correctly seems like it would be massively complex, if it's even possible. ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><x><y a="/>" b='/>' c="'" d='"' e=">"></y></x>```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that's why I asked, if this is a simple template conversion for elements without attributes it may be worth it, but since your question is much more relevant I was waiting for an answer to it

Comment: @Kaddath - Sorry, that wasn't supposed to be @ you, it was supposed to be @ user2950720! It started as a comment to you, then I re-read what you'd written and realized you were saying the same thing. So I reworded the comment but forgot to remove the @! Sorry about that. :-)

Comment: The OP could create an XMLDocument via [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) like e.g. `const doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');`. But then the OP needs to write own serializing functionality since the [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)'s [`serializeToString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) method will serialize each empty node into its empty tag representation.

Comment: @user2950720 ... Does the OP still participate in this thread?

Comment: @user2950720 ... From the so far provided answers / approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments ...

> *"The OP could create an XMLDocument via [`DOMParser.parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) like e.g. `const doc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');`. But then the OP needs to write own serializing functionality since the [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)'s [`serializeToString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString) method will serialize each empty node into its empty tag representation."*

The next provided example code comes with a custom serializer in order to prove that the suggested approach can be implemented with not that much effort.

```js
const data = `<users lang="en">
  <user uuid="1232-3965-6923-2887">
    <firstname>test</firstname>
    <lastname/>
    <age type="integer"/>
  </user>
</users>`;

const xmlDoc = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

const xmlSerializerMarkup = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
const documentElementMarkup = xmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML;

console.log('originally provided markup...\n', data);

console.log('XMLSerializer markup...\n', xmlSerializerMarkup);
console.log('documentElement markup...\n', documentElementMarkup);

function serialize(elmNode, indention = '') {
  const { nodeName, childElementCount } = elmNode;

  let currentMarkup = elmNode
    .getAttributeNames()
    .reduce((markup, attrName) => [
        markup,
        ' ',
        attrName,
        '="',
        elmNode.getAttribute(attrName),
        '"',
    ].join(''), `${ indention }<${ nodeName }`);

  if (childElementCount === 0) {
    const { textContent } = elmNode;

    if (textContent === '') {
      // entirely empty element node.

      // do not implement/support the empty tag style.
      currentMarkup = currentMarkup + `><\/${ nodeName }>`;
    } else {
      currentMarkup = [
        currentMarkup,
        '>',
        textContent,
        `<\/${ nodeName }>`,
      ].join('');
    }
  } else {
    let nestedMarkup = '';

    [...elmNode.children]
      .forEach(childElement => {
        nestedMarkup = [
          nestedMarkup,
          serialize(childElement, (indention + '  ')),
        ].join('\n');
      });

    currentMarkup = [
      currentMarkup,
      nestedMarkup,
    ].join('>') + `\n${ indention }<\/${ nodeName }>`;
  }
  return currentMarkup;
}
const customSerializerMarkup = serialize(xmlDoc.documentElement);

console.log('custom serializer markup...\n', customSerializerMarkup);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind using/adapting something like [JsStAX](https://gitlab.com/publishing-systems/JsStAX/-/tree/master) (full disclosure: a little portation project of mine to make an implementation of [Java's Streaming API for XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) available in JavaScript)?

Benefit is that with the outer event loop, you have pretty good control over what output you want to generate, as well as no trouble with any variations in the XML format.

Is it too heavy, are required/desired features missing (as it's not XML-feature-complete), objecting to the license? But does the job, apart from the many possible improvements or other, potentially better solutions.